# Configure auto shrink sqlite database file with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I have problem with setting sqlite database file to auto shrink. The code I'm using to configure database is:

```
Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString("PRAGMA auto_vacuum=FULL").UsingFile("file.sqlite"))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Application.NHibernateSessionManager>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

After creating ~15000 records database file is ~1MB large. When I delete everything the database file is still ~1MB.

How do you configure sqlite using fluent nhibernate to work with pragma "auto_vacuum"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this applies to auto_vacuum, but with other pragmas, I configure the db "normally", then execute the pragma as an update, for example:

```
SessionManager.CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery(String.Format("PRAGMA user_version = {0}", version)).ExecuteUpdate();
```

This was initialized using FluentNHibernate like this:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(dbPath)...
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work with PRAGMA auto_vacuum, because as documentation say "auto-vacuuming must be turned on before any tables are created. It is not possible to enable or disable auto-vacuum after a table has been created".

Comment: Well then just run it once before creating any tables, have you tried that? (Just guessing here)